# Is there a way to retrieve all objects in a query that were initially stored as an array?

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

After storing an array of objects using `put()` method, I am only able to retrieve the last object.

```kotlin
var saleBookCopies:List<SaleBookCopy> = saleBook.book_copies 
//saleBook.book_copies is an array of 30 objects

saleBookCopy.put(saleBookCopies)
```

Retrieving

```kotlin
var saleBookCopies = saleBookCopyBox.query().equal(SaleBookCopy_id,bookId.toLong()).build().find()
```

The result of the above query is a single object, and the array size is 1.

I've tried using a `for` loop to store the objects but still results in a single object array.

```kotlin
for(saleBookCopy in saleBookCopies){
saleBookCopyBox.put(saleBookCopy)
}
```

Comment: Can you share what `SaleBookCopy` looks like and what data you are storing? It would make sense that there is only a single `SaleBookCopy` with the ID `bookId` as each has a unique ID.

Comment: Hi @Uwe-ObjectBox thanks for the concern. I figured out the problem and detailed my solution in the post below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem a few days ago, but forgot to remove it.
However for the sake of anyone who may face the same issue, here's the solution.

> The list of `SaleBookCopy` objects in the json response had the **same value** in the `id` field.
> Therefore, when they were mapped to Kotlin `SaleBookCopy` objects (via the for-loop above) object-box would **overwrite** the initial object.

I had my backend developer tweak his API response for that endpoint and solved the issue!.